# Jquery: How to attach an event handler to a different element and event

Tags: jquery, events

I have an indepth complicated set of jquery code, which is triggered with

`$(basketUpdateTrigger).click(function() {...`

What I need to do is trigger the same set of code when `$('select').change` happens - that is, when the selected option of a dropdoan box is changed.

I looked at .bind() but that just does not seem to answer the problem.

Comment: You could just put the code in a function and assign that as the event handler - `$(basketUpdateTrigger).click(yourFunction);` and `$('select').change(yourFunction);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually invoke the click handler when the select element changes:

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    $(basketUpdateTrigger).trigger("click");
});
```

Alternately, you can wrap the logic inside a named function; then assign that function to click and change event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

u can use bind method to attach an eventhandler

```
    $('#btn').bind('click', function()
      {
            // TO DO
      }
    );
```